# PHP, javascript around a link

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a small piece of javascript to get a user to confirm things on my website. I have a link that I also ask them to confirm before proceeding. I've used the 'onclick' function with buttons no problem, but how do I use it on a link?

Heres my link:

```
echo"<a href=\"$urlHTML\">Delete</a>";
```

And heres my 'onclick':

```
onclick="return confirm('Please confirm you wish to edit these details')"/>
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onclick on an anchor tag the same way you'd use it on a button:

```
<a href="<?php echo $urlHTML; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Please confirm you wish to edit these details');">Delete</a>
```

However you'd be better off using an event handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myClickHandler() {
        return confirm("Really?");
    }

    document.getElementById("my_link").onclick = myClickHandler;
</script>

<a id="my_link" href="<?php echo $urlHTML; ?>">Delete</a>
```

I recommend you also read up on [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: @ twaddington how would i use your 'anchor tag' method with it echo'd and with the '$html' link i posted. Im new to javascript. Ty

Answer (score 2):

Ummm...

```
<?php ?>
<a href="<?php echo $urlHTML ?>" onclick="return confirm(blah blah blah)">Delete</a>
```

Comment: @ marc b    echo"<a href="<?echo $urlHTML?>" onclick="return confirm(Please Confirm You Wish to Add these Details)">Delete</a>";

Comment: Any chance you could give me an idea why im getting a 'unexpected '?'' error from this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) and [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (IE) instead of using inline JavaScript.